# Accessing the values within a list and if that value contains in python3 - IndexError to scalar value

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, pandas, slice

```
class BarcodeAnalyser():
def __init__(self):
    self.rangeTrueBarcarodesfirst =[]
    self.rangeTrueBarcodesecond = []
    self.rangeTrueBarcodethird = []
    self.isBrange1 = []
    self.isBrange2 = []
    self.isBrange3 = []

def isthere5or8(self):
    for values in self.rangeTrueBarcarodesfirst:
        if (values[2:] == '5' or values[2:] == '8') and (values[7:] == '5' or values[7:] == '8'):
            self.isBrange1.append(values)
            print("this is identified bcode in this range(2456500 - 2556499): " + str(self.isBrange1))
            if values is None:
                break
    for values2 in self.rangeTrueBarcodesecond:
        if (values2[2:] == '5' or values2[2:] == '8') and (values2[7:] == '5' or values2[7:] == '8'):
            self.isBrange2.append(values2)
            print("this is identified bcode in this range(8500000 - 9499999): " + str(self.isBsrange2))
            if values2 is None:
                break
    for values3 in self.rangeTrueBarcodethird:
        if(values3[2:] == '5' or values3[2:] == '8') and (values3[7:] == '5' or values3[7:] == '8'):
            self.isBrange3.append(values3)
            print("this is identified bcode in this range (9790681 - 9815680): " + str(self.isBrange3))
            if values3 is None:
                break
```

The output of the above code is:

```
if (values[2:] == '5' or values[2:] == '8') and (values[7:] == '5' or values[7:] == '8'):
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

The contents of the lists `rangeTrueBarcodefirst`, `rangeTrueBarcodesecond` and `rangeTrueBarcodethird` are in a format like this: `[9369181, 8668489]`

I am simply trying to slice, if the value index 2 and 8 is equal to 5 or 8 append them on them on their appropriate list.

Am I doing it properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Original:**

The key point is that you are attempting to slice something that does not support slicing. For example, `987[1]` throws an error, rather than returning `8`, because integers don't support slicing.

It seems that `rangeTrueBarcodesfirst` is a list containing numbers. Example from your post:

```
rangeTrueBarcodesfirst = [9369181, 8668489]
```

However, look at a simplified version of your loop:

```
for values in rangeTrueBarcodesfirst:
    if values[2:] == '5':
        print(True)
```

So the first time through, `values == 9369181`, which is an integer. You can't slice an integer, so your error is happening when you try `values[2:]`. You probably want to cast `values` to a string at some point, like so:

```
for values in rangeTrueBarcodesfirst:
    string_values = str(values)
    if string_values[2:] == '5':
        print True
```

Three additional thoughts:

1. `values` is an odd name for this variable, since it is just one value (whether a string or integer). Why not call it something more descriptive, like `barcode`?
2. Depending on the rest of your program, you might want to store the `barcode`s as strings the whole way through. Do you ever depend on them being integers?
3. Googling for your error makes it seem like some of this data is in `pandas` or `numpy` datatypes -- so if this doesn't solve your problem, I'd suggest posting the code that leads to the construction of `rangeTrueBarcodesfirst`.

--

**Edit:**

There is more going on in your example that I realized at first. The basic idea (think hard about what's in the `values` variable) is the same, but here are some more notes (assuming that `values` is supposed to be as string).

First, `values[2:] == '5'` -- the left side is looking at a slice of a string, not a single character, so this will only be `True` if `values` has length exactly 3. For example, `'abc'[2:] == 'c'`, but `'abcd'[2:] == 'cd'`.

So either you have a bug, or you are expecting a list of length 3. In the first case, you probably mean `values[2]` (note no `:`). In the second case, you're in trouble again because in the same line you're looking at `values[7:]`. If the string is too short, this will return an empty string (`''`).

So in other words, the following expression will always be false, no matter what's in `values`:

```
(values[2:] == '5') and (values[7:] != '')
```